# Why my form only work in chrome when Js is active?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

To submit my form, the user need choice the price of your ticket by html droplist.

Here is JS the code:

```
var ticket = document.getElementById('ticket-box');
var member = document.getElementById('member');
var form = document.getElementById('form');

form.style.display = 'none';
ticket.style.display = 'none';

member.addEventListener('change', function() {
  var chosen = member.options[member.selectedIndex].index;


  if(chosen == 1) {
    form.style.display = 'inline-block';
    ticket.style.display = 'inline-block';
    form.selectedIndex = 2;
    form.options[0].style.display = 'none';
    form.options[1].style.display = 'none';
    form.options[2].style.display = 'inline-block';
    form.options[3].style.display = 'inline-block';
    form.options[4].style.display = 'none';
    form.options[5].style.display = 'none';

$(function() {
   $('#btnget').click(function(e) {

      let formValido =  document
    .getElementById("formulario")
    .checkValidity();

      if(formValido){
         $("#formulario")
         .attr("action", $('#form').val())
         .submit();
      }
   })
});
  }  
  });
```

This only works in chrome (email is comming only in chrome).

Why is this happening?

form link: http://www.congressoprotecaodados.com.br/inscricao/form22.html

Comment: Please specify in what other browsers you have tested this code. Also version of same.

Comment: mozilla and firefox dont works, the infos dont comes to my email

Comment: i discovery that when i remove  style.display = 'none' that works, how i can substitue that?

Comment: `mozilla` and `firefox`? They are not different. `Mozilla Firefox`.

Comment: mozilla and ie sry

Answer (score 0):

maybe you are using some javascript function or keyword which is only support to chrome .Please refer mozilla develope netword to check browser support for any javascript built in function .